# How to set %variable%=%variable% using batch files

Tags: command-line

I have two batch files.

File a:

```
SET Variablex=0
```

File b:

```
SET Variabley=1
SET %Variablex%=%Variabley%
ECHO %Variablex%
```

The result is 0 and not 1 as expected. I tried various options such as quotes, exclamation etc.

Answer (score 0):

The value of VariableX is lost when batch file a has done executing. 
If you call file b from within file a, then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

File b:

```
SET "Variabley=1"
SET "Variablex=%Variabley%"
ECHO %Variablex%
```